# Proving $A\setminus B$ is an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove that if
>
> - $A\cap B\subsetneq A\cap C$, and
> - there is an injective function between $A\setminus C$ and $A\setminus B,$
>
> then $A\setminus B$ is an infinite set.

I know that if I can prove $A\setminus B\supsetneq A\setminus C$ I'm done but I'm just struggling to do it.

I've tried to proof it with definitions of intersection and relative complement but didn't succeed. I've tried to prove it also by contradiction but didn't succeed also.

Comment: $(A\cap X)\cup (A\setminus X)=A$.

Comment: Also, dangerous to use "injective function between $X$ and $Y.$" Always say "from $X$ to $Y.$" Between tends to be a symmetric word, which is okay for bijections.

Comment: Does $\subset$ mean a strict subset? Otherwise, consider $B=C=\{\}$.

Comment: Please show your trials to prove it: the definitions of intersections and relative complement.  Whether you succeeded or not.  Same request of your attempt to prove the statement by contradiction.  Whether successful or not.  That's the best way of helping us help you.  Otherwise, it sounds like you're just making unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: Every second you fail to clarify this question is time other people are wasting trying to help you solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @amWhy My trials to prove are involving hebrew and to write everything here again will be big pain for me - will uploading my trials (that involve hebrew) will also be ok?

Comment: @EranAnton I can understand the dilemma you're in.  Just in the future, try to include some highlights of your workings, formatting them in mathjax, okay?

Comment: This theorem is true if you had an injection *from* $A\setminus B$ *to* $A\setminus C.$ Given right-to-left language of Hebrew versus left-to-right of English, did you mean the opposite direction of the inhjection?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the real Data (Sorry my English\Math Englise is not so good - maybe item of data is the correct say?) was A\C equivalent (again not sure the right expression so thats why I just said the definition of it) A\B.

Comment: That means a bijection, not an injection.

Comment: So it now looks like the assumptions are $A\cap B\subsetneq A\cap C$ and there is a bijection between $A\smallsetminus C$ and $A\smallsetminus B$ which, from what you say immediately following the highlighted part, is a problem you should know how to solve.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Im very very sorry if so but I went to my notebook again to confirm it and notebook said as I mentioned - "2 sets are "equivalent" when there is an injection between them."

Comment: @Eran Then you wrote the wrong thing in your notebook, unless you mean that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent when there is an injection from $A$ to $B$ and one from $B$ to $A$. (As pointed out "injection between them" is ambiguous.)

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false as written.  Take $A=\{1\}$, $B=C=\{2\}$.  Then $A\cap B=A\cap C=\emptyset$ and the identity function maps $A\setminus C=A$ to $A\setminus B=A$.  However, $A\setminus A$ is not an infinite set.

---

If $\subset$ means strict subset, then take $A=C=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$, and the same problem arises.  The empty function maps $A\setminus C=\emptyset$ to $A\setminus B=B$.

Comment: Depends, some people use that $X\subset Y$ means $X\subsetneq Y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  If so, it's important they say so, yes?

Comment: @amWhy While I'd expect a mathematician to say so, the question is likely coming from someone who *doesn't know* to say so.

Comment: moot point, unless "between $X$ and $Y$" means "to $X$ from $Y$".

Comment: Perhaps, but it's also coming from someone who's made a lot of claims and nothing to show for it.  Go wonder?

Comment: @amWhy All the more pointless to answer the question, when it is easily debunked. Expect the question to change...

Comment: I did mean X⊊Y - sorry - didnt know its not the same all over the world

Comment: It's still not true in that case, @EranAnton, as the latter part of vadim's answer shows.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  I do not disagree with you!

Comment: @vadim123 Given that the person is translating from right-to-left Hebrew, it's actually possible that the question mean't "to $X$ from $Y$." :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews https://gyazo.com/a037d7eb6bf5f11de112c7ce38985e81